# how to display product option on featured module or featured product of opencart

Tags: opencart

I am using the featured module to list products to my homepage. But while the product option works fine in the product details page, it doesnt work well in the homepage(featured module). The option values for the last product is getting repeated to all the product listings. Also add to cart has some problem. Can anyone provide a proper solution to this?

Code is as follows :

controller:

```php
      $this->data['products'] = array();

      $products = explode(',', $this->config->get('featured_product'));     

      if (empty($setting['limit'])) {
         $setting['limit'] = 5;
      }

      $products = array_slice($products, 0, (int)$setting['limit']);

      foreach ($products as $product_id) {
         $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);

         if ($product_info) {
            if ($product_info['image']) {
               $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_info['image'], $setting['image_width'], $setting['image_height']);
            } else {
               $image = false;
            }

            if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
               $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
            } else {
               $price = false;
            }

            if ((float)$product_info['special']) {
               $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['special'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
            } else {
               $special = false;
            }

            if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
               $rating = $product_info['rating'];
            } else {
               $rating = false;
            }
            $this->data['products'][] = array(
               'product_id' => $product_info['product_id'],
               'thumb'       => $image,
               'name'        => $product_info['name'],
               'price'       => $price,
               'product_description'       => $product_info['product_description'],
               'special'     => $special,
               'rating'     => $rating,
               'reviews'    => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$product_info['reviews']),
               'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product_info['product_id']),
            );   


         $this->data['options'] = array();
         //print_r($this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($this->request->get['product_id']));
         //die("");
         $option=$this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($product_id);
         //foreach ($this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($product_id) as $option) //{

               $option_value_data = array();

               foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) {
                  if (!$option_value['subtract'] || ($option_value['quantity'] > 0)) {
                     if ((($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) && (float)$option_value['price']) {
                        $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($option_value['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
                     } else {
                        $price = false;
                     }

                     $option_value_data[] = array(
                        'product_option_value_id' => $option_value['product_option_value_id'],
                        'option_value_id'         => $option_value['option_value_id'],
                        'name'                    => $option_value['name'],
                        'image'                   => $this->model_tool_image->resize($option_value['image'], 50, 50),
                        'price'                   => $price,
                        'price_prefix'            => $option_value['price_prefix']
                     );
                  }
               }

               $this->data['options'][] = array(
                  'product_option_id' => $option['product_option_id'],
                  'option_id'         => $option['option_id'],
                  'name'              => $option['name'],
                  'type'              => $option['type'],
                  'option_value'      => $option_value_data,
                  'required'          => $option['required']
               );               

         //}

      }
      }
```

view:

```html
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>

<a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></a>   

<?php if ($options) {  ?>
      <div class="options" style="color: #457A33; float: left;line-height: 23px; margin-right: 20px; width:300px;">

        <?php foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'select') { ?>
        <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option" style="float:left; width:150px;">
          <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
          <span class="required">*</span>
          <?php } ?>
          <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
          <select name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]">
            <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
            <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
            <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
            (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
            <?php } ?>
            </option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>
          <br />
           <a href="#">What's this</a>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>
 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The *options* has to be assigned to the concrete product - so populated and processed before `$this->data['products'][] = array(...);`:

```php
      $this->data['products'] = array();

      $products = explode(',', $this->config->get('featured_product'));     

      if (empty($setting['limit'])) {
         $setting['limit'] = 5;
      }

      $products = array_slice($products, 0, (int)$setting['limit']);

      foreach ($products as $product_id) {
         $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);

         if ($product_info) {
            if ($product_info['image']) {
               $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_info['image'], $setting['image_width'], $setting['image_height']);
            } else {
               $image = false;
            }

            if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
               $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
            } else {
               $price = false;
            }

            if ((float)$product_info['special']) {
               $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['special'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
            } else {
               $special = false;
            }

            if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
               $rating = $product_info['rating'];
            } else {
               $rating = false;
            }

            $options = array();

            foreach ($this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($product_id) as $option) {

               $option_value_data = array();

               foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) {
                  if (!$option_value['subtract'] || ($option_value['quantity'] > 0)) {
                     if ((($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) && (float)$option_value['price']) {
                        $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($option_value['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
                     } else {
                        $price = false;
                     }

                     $option_value_data[] = array(
                        'product_option_value_id' => $option_value['product_option_value_id'],
                        'option_value_id'         => $option_value['option_value_id'],
                        'name'                    => $option_value['name'],
                        'image'                   => $this->model_tool_image->resize($option_value['image'], 50, 50),
                        'price'                   => $price,
                        'price_prefix'            => $option_value['price_prefix']
                     );
                  }
               }

               $options[] = array(
                  'product_option_id' => $option['product_option_id'],
                  'option_id'         => $option['option_id'],
                  'name'              => $option['name'],
                  'type'              => $option['type'],
                  'option_value'      => $option_value_data,
                  'required'          => $option['required']
               );               
            }

            $this->data['products'][] = array(
               'product_id' => $product_info['product_id'],
               'thumb'       => $image,
               'name'        => $product_info['name'],
               'price'       => $price,
               'product_description'       => $product_info['product_description'],
               'special'     => $special,
               'rating'     => $rating,
               'reviews'    => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$product_info['reviews']),
               'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product_info['product_id']),
               'options'     => $options,
            );   
      }
```

Now You should have the options loaded in each product respectively. Just modify your template accordingly:

```php
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>

<a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></a>   

<?php if ($product['options']) {  ?>
      <div class="options" style="color: #457A33; float: left;line-height: 23px; margin-right: 20px; width:300px;">

        <?php foreach ($product['options'] as $option) { ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'select') { ?>
        <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option" style="float:left; width:150px;">
          <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
          <span class="required">*</span>
          <?php } ?>
          <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
          <select name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]">
            <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
            <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
            <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
            (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
            <?php } ?>
            </option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>
          <br />
           <a href="#">What's this</a>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: i had to modify some of the variable names to use this with my installation, but it kinda worked!... now i'm seeing the drop-downs for the required options right where i need them, but i'm getting php notices about how result is an undefined variable and how product_total is an undefined index..  to make matters worse, the notices are coming from the vq-cached file, and there are no traces anywhere in the controller code of the undefined variable or or the undefined index.  can you shed some light on how the vq-cache files are generated?

Comment: taking matters into my own hands, i found out that because they were in the vq-cache files, these errors were being caused by vqmod itself, it was using an outdated variable scheme in the category controller file and much like i had to do with the provided code, instances of result were replaced with product_info and voila! i hope this helps future inquisitors on the topic!